# What is the Jewish view on Adam's footprint in Sri Lanka?

Tags: adam

There's [a certain mark and a peak called adam's peak in Sri Lanka](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam%27s_Peak) has a not jewish tradition that it is Adam's footprint. Does Judaism have any tradition about this mark? I would like to see the Torah sources if they exist on this subject.

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect that Judaism would have anything to say about this belief of another religion?

Comment: @IsaacMoses My original question was about the physical place it was fixed into this.

Comment: @hazoriz I've looked at the [revision history](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/50713/revisions); I don't see that anyone changed your intent in the question at any point, though I could be missing something. If you'd like to clarify your question, please keep in mind that you can always [edit] it yourself.

Comment: That said, I don't see how any of that has relevance to @IsaacMoses's point: what makes you think that Judaism has anything to say about Adam's Peak, or the footprint found there?

Comment: @Shokhet nothing (just I tout that they take things from judaism and try to stay away from paganism, so maybe they had a jewish source) that is why is am asking, my question is not about the belief but about the actual thing

Comment: If that was part of your motivation, you should probably [edit] that in.....although I don't know if that's enough to make it on-topic (the close reason for "comparative religion" questions says "Questions about comparative religion, and questions about what others have written about Judaism, are off-topic on Mi Yodeya. This includes any question that requires of its answerers any knowledge of a religion besides Judaism." ....I'm not sure if that applies to this question.)

Answer (score 3):

This mountain in Sri Lanka isn't mentioned in Tanach, Gemara, or the Rishonim. I don't think that there is an official Jewish position on the rock formation at the top, but in my humble opinion, the claim is highly suspect as there are two other opinions that state that this rock formation is Buddha's or Rama's footprint. Buddha and Rama were known to live in the India area and the footprint is more likely to belong to one of them.

Comment: Is it possible that it is the same person adom, Buddha and Rama And it is just that they made different stories?

Comment: @hazoriz Doubtful. I don't know who Rama is, off-hand, but no story I know about the Buddha claimed that he was the first man -- Adam alone has that claim, AFAIK.

Comment: I don't doubt you're correct, but am curious as the basis for your claim that _rishonim_ don't mention the mountain.

Comment: Because it is all the way in Sri Lanka.